# What does a quantum mechanics magician do?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, terminology

Thousands of years ago a coppersmith was a magician doing stuff most couldn't fathom, a few decades ago a computer programmer was a magician doing stuff most couldn't fathom.

If a quantum mechanical magician made a lead bar into a gold bar, in addition to performing his magic, was he applying quantum mechanics or utilizising quantum mechanics? I assume employing quantum mechanics is out of the question.

English is not my native tongue, so feel free to correct my wording or spelling or tagging.

Comment: Putting aside the fact that quantum mechanics cannot turn a lead bar into a gold bar, I think any of *using, applying, utilizing, employing* would be an appropriate verb here.

Comment: Employing a quantum mechanic isn't a good idea.  You never know what state he's in or when he's going to another state.  If you try to keep track of where he is, you can't tell what he's doing; and if you try to keep track of what he's doing, you can't tell where he is.

Comment: @PeterShor I know using covers it, but it covers a lot.

Comment: @deadrat Haven't thought of it like that, but fully agree.

Answer (score 1):

> Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.[<sup>1</sup>](http://www.clarkefoundation.org/sample-page/sir-arthurs-quotations/)
>
> [Arthur C. Clarke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthur_C._Clarke)

Thousands of years later a coppersmith is still a magician doing stuff most couldn't fathom.  Just try hiring one to fit your pipes, watch, and see how much of your bill you understand.

A few decades later, as a computer programmer myself, I can tell you, we're still magicians doing stuff our pointy haired managers don't understand.

What were talking about here is specializing.  Thousands of years ago most of us specialized in agriculture.  The few who didn't were weird and mysterious.  Now most of us specialize in office work.  The few who don't are weird and mysterious.  At least to us office denizens.

So, as Clarke would point out, if a quantum mechanical magician made a lead bar into a gold bar the quantum mechanics would not be in addition to the magic.  It would be the magic.

Saying you used/applied/utilized/employed quantum mechanics to turn lead into gold is like saying you used/applied/utilized/employed gravity when you took the elevator.  Sure it's 100% true but it tells you next to nothing about what's really going on.  After reading this you probably know nothing more about how elevators work than you knew before.  And telling you nothing while sounding impressive is the very heart of politics, oops I mean magic.

Now the skeptical reader may be thinking that there is no way anyone can turn lead into gold without "real" magic.  The truth is, it's been done.  A long time ago.  Well, technically, they used the element bismuth.

> In 1980, when the bismuth-to-gold experiment was carried out, running particle beams through the Bevalac cost about $5,000 an hour, “and we probably used about a day of beam time,” recalls Oregon State University nuclear chemist Walter Loveland, one of the researchers on the project. Glenn Seaborg, who shared the 1951 Nobel Prize in Chemistry for his work with heavy elements and who died in 1999, was the senior author on the resulting study. “It would cost more than one quadrillion dollars per ounce to produce gold by this experiment," Seaborg told the Associated Press that year. The going rate for an ounce of gold at the time? About $560.
>
> [Fact or Fiction?: Lead Can Be Turned into Gold - By John Matson - Scientific American](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article/fact-or-fiction-lead-can-be-turned-into-gold/)

So,

> What does a quantum mechanics magician do?

They turn clickbait headlines into research grants.  That's the real magic.

Comment: You forget the corrolary: Sufficiently advanced magic is indistinguishable from technology :-)